# Accessing tableview content outside cellforrow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view in which i have a button at the top and a tableview with custom cell at bottom in
       custom cell i have a text field, am trying to access text field content outside tableview cell                       for row method on tap of that button on the top, only the the text of cells which were visible is   getting displayed, if am scrolled to top and tapped on save, bottom text field values were nil, if i scroll to bottom and tap on save bottom text field values are nil, i guess it has some thing to do with dequeue resuable cell with identifier.

//tableview method

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AcessoryCell";

    AcessoryCell *cell = (AcessoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AcessoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    }




for (NSInteger i=0; i<selectedButtonsArray.count; i++)
{

    NSNumber * num = [selectedButtonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[num intValue] inSection:0];
    AcessoryCell *cell = (AcessoryCell *) [self.acessoryTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"text field text is %@", cell.celltextField.text);


}
```

log is

```
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is (null)
text is (null)
```

if i scroll to bottom then log is

```
text is (null)
text is (null) 
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
text is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this its working :

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:YOUR_ROW inSection:YOUR_SECTION];

UITableViewCell* cell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.textColor = YOUR_COLOR;
[yourTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: My table view has a custom text filed in it, if i use the above code i will not be able to access cell.cellTextFiled.Text

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here you need to give an identifier to each cell, when you use `static` identifier it will not load each cell in memory.

You have to give an unique identifier to load all the cells in UITableView and remains as it is when you scroll UITableView.

Replace this line

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AcessoryCell";
```

With this

```
NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AcessoryCell";
```

**EDIT:**

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AcessoryCell";

    AcessoryCell *cell = (AcessoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
//.... do your stuff
}
```

Comment: if i try accessing cell through     AcessoryCell *cell = (AcessoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[self cellIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath] forIndexPath:indexPath];
 am getting an error no visible @interface for "class" declares the selector  cellIdentifierForIndexPath

Comment: @SyedIsmailAhamed Try removing `static` keyword, check edited answer

Comment: Tried removing static keyword as well no luck :(

Comment: @SyedIsmailAhamed - Have you registered your nib for cell identifier in `-viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes i did  UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AcessoryCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.acessoryTableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"AcessoryCell"];

Comment: @SyedIsmailAhamed - Remove `if` condition part, because when you register from `-viewDidLoad` not need to check cell is nil or not.

Comment: did that, but its still the same

Answer (score 0):

I hope , you are displaying different values for text fields based on the row.
Use the same logic to get the values of the text fields.

Are you using Array of values to display in text fields based on the row?

Comment: initially text field values are hard coded to 1, then later on based on user input text file values are being saved, only the values of cells which are visible are getting displayed.

Comment: So, Are you using initial array with value of "1". If not, first create an array with same size as no of rows with values empty or "1". When ever user editing the text field (textFieldDidChange) update the array values. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let cell :SampleTableCell = sampleTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! SampleTableCell
```