# How to get a cell without calling cellForRowAtIndexPath in objective C iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

We can get a cell from:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:tableVie cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

but it will calling the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

if I know the cell's tag or indexPath , it's there a way to get the specified cell without to calling   `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

---

Add some reason why I can't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

I want to get the cell in the method cellForHeightAtIndexPath to reset the height of each cell. :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CommentsListResponseDataModel * model = self.liveCommentData[indexPath.row -1];

        if (model.viewHeight > 0) {
            return model.viewHeight;
        } else {
            if (model.parentComment) {
                CommentParentCell * cc = (CommentParentCell *)cell;
                return cc.viewHeight;
            } else {
                CommentSingleCell * cc = (CommentSingleCell *)cell;
                return cc.viewHeight;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But this will become a dead loop because it all `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` will recall `cellForHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath`

Comment: Whats wrong with the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Desdenova I pass a model to cell and override model's setter method to config the cell (in cellForRowAtIndexPath) , if cellForRowAtIndexPath called many times, it will setup cell multi times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing tableview content outside cellforrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709483/accessing-tableview-content-outside-cellforrow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of my understanding, you are trying to get the cell object by calling **UITableView datasource** method. But when you try to do like that then it will be infinite loop call and you will never get the cell object. So in order to get cell object from UITableView, do the following steps.

- Declare your UITableView as global to the your ViewController, something like `UITableView *_tableView;` or `@IBOutlet weak UITableView *_tableView;`
- Then try to call the

> ```
> //specify the item indexpath
> NSIndexPath *_indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:3 inSection:1];
>
> //now try to access cell object by passing cell indexPath
> UITableViewCell *_cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_indexPath];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something unrelated to your original question - you want your table view cells to size automatically, depending on content.

What you need to do is:
1. add constraints to your cell - make sure it doesn't have a height constraint, but its content must have Top and Bottom constraints.
2. remove `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as it will not be necessary
3. set your table view row height to automatic

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Now just setup your cell - resize its content to desired height and table cell will automatically be resized